# How to Replace double character

Tags: c#, regex

```
string originalString = "anna";
var result = Regex.Replace(originalString, @"O\(*?\)", "c");
Console.WriteLine(originalString);
```

`*` means "zero or more of the preceding character"

I can't understand where I'm wrong, in practice it should replace the character `a` and the character `n` because they are repeated more than once within my string so they should be replaced with the letter `c`.

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(result);`

Comment: You expression will match a capital O followed by 0 or more `(` and then a `)`.  You'd want `(.)\1+` to match repeating characters, but then it would only match them if they are beside each other and "anna" would become "aca".  What result do you want "cccc" or "cc" or just "c"?

Answer (score 1):

Use the back-reference `(.)\1` to match a characters that appears twice.

The regex you provided is, and I'm sorry to say that, completely wrong.
Here is breakdown of your regex pattern:
`O\(*?\)`

- `O` matches the character `O` literally
- `\(` matches the character `(` literally
- `*?` matches preceding character zero or more times in non-greedy manner
- `\)` matches the character `)` literally

Comment: @juharr You're right, thanks for the correction